# How to decrypt/decode the strings found in desktop application with x64dbg?

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

I'm a beginner and I have no experience at all in Reverse Engineering. I want to study it so find the "string" references, but all I get is some incomprehensible strings which are probably encoded or something like that.

I'm searching for a string: `OK! Expires:`

Is there a way to decode them so they became readable ?

Here is what I got so far by search for a string references in All modules:

[image]

I tried to start debugging, which was working today, but now suddenly it denies to work. Each time I attach the running app, it gives me an error (I've censored the application name for some reason):

[image]

Comment: I have some questions about your question, have you checked if the binary is protected? can you debug normally?

Comment: No I didn't checked that, I'm an absolute beginner in RE. But I managed to somehow debug step by step the app, but I can no more reproduce it. I've launched a x64dbg first, then the app alone, and lastly I've attached the process (target), that was the only way to run the debug correctly